# The distance between the two interacting particles is smaller than cutoff distance

Tags: python, montecarlo

I'm getting this error. The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Here is my code. I'm getting error in the function "cal_total_pair_energy" rij < cutoff.

```py
# Generate initial state
def generate_initial_coordinates(num_particles=100):
    coordinates = np.random.randint(num_particles, size=(3  , 3)) 
    return coordinates

def L_J_potential(rij):
    epsilon = 0.6
    sigma = 1.0
    V = 4.0 * epsilon * ((sigma / rij)**12 - (sigma / rij)**6)
    return V

def FENE_potential(rij):
    R = 0.3
    K = 40.0
    V_FENE = 0.5 * K * R**2.0 * np.log(1.0 - (rij / R)**2.0)
    return V_FENE

def particle_distance(r_i, r_j):
    rij = r_i - r_j
    return rij

def cal_total_pair_energy(coordinates, cutoff):
    e_nb = 0.0
    particle_count = len(coordinates)
    for i_particle in range(particle_count):
        for j_particle in range(i_particle):
            r_i = coordinates[i_particle]
            r_j = coordinates[j_particle]
            rij = particle_distance(r_i, r_j)

            if rij < cutoff:
                e_pair = L_J_potential(rij)
                e_nb += e_pair

    e_bond = 0.0
    for i_particle in range(particle_count-2):
        e_bond += FENE_potential(rij)

    e_tot = e_nb + e_bond
    return e_tot

sigma = 0.6
cutoff = 2.5 * sigma
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `r_i` and `r_j` are both arrays of coordinates, and thus distance between them is not just difference, but a norm of it. Thus:

```
def particle_distance(r_i, r_j):
    rij = numpy.linalg.norm(r_i - r_j)
    return rij
```

Notice use of numpy.linalg.norm.